# javascript input is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code:

```
var input = addInput('text', 'input-text', 'inputId');
var button = addInput('submit', 'input-button', 'buttonId');

button.setAttribute("value", 'Click');

var fileref = document.createElement('script');

fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
fileref.src = "../resources/js/script.js";

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref);

pane.appendChild(input);
pane.appendChild(button);

button.onclick = function() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('inputId').value;
  alert(inp);
}
```

in this code i try to dynamically add button and input text. Everything worked fine but when i added

> resources/js/script.js

input text doesn't work, i.e disabled

Comment: That is great. What is `script.js`? Are you trying to reference something from it before it has finished loading in? Do you get any error messages in your _Console_?

Comment: press f12 and go to console tab check whats error there.

Comment: May be failed to load resource: /resources/js/script.js. ie the relative path to script.js may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

where is your implementation of addInput() method?

Answer (score 0):

```
function addInput(type,className,id)
                {
                    var input=document.createElement('input');
                    input.type=type;
                    input.classList.add(className);
                    input.setAttribute('id',id);
                    return input;
                    }
```

i tested script file, it works. Everything works fine in script.js, only input  elements doesn't work.